# Delete nodes composing a polygon in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon

I want to delete a specific node of a polygon. I have tried using `ST_RemovePoint` but it only works with linestring type. For example, I have the polygon `POLYGON((20 50, 120 50, 120 70, 170 70, 20 70, 20 50, 20 50))` and I would like to delete the node with coordinates `120 70`.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `ST_DumpPoints`, `ST_MakeLine` and `ST_MakePolygon` should help you here. You could remove the nodes you don't want in the final new polygon in the WHERE clause.

Related:

- [Dumping Points from Polygon and do st_makeline with these?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222453/dumping-points-from-polygon-and-do-st-makeline-with-these)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046642/convert-points-to-polygon-using-postgis

Answer (score 1):

You could use `st_exteriorring` to get the linestring that makes up the polygon and remove the point and then `st_makepolgon` on the result.